# Accessing d3.js element attributes from the datum?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm trying to access the cx & cy attributes of some specific svg circles which i have already drawn to the screen using d3.js's .data() function, can anyone help out? The code that's trying to access it is below.

```
d3.selectAll(".mynode").each( function(d, i){
  if(d.someId == targetId){
    console.log( d.attr("cx") );    // just trying to demo my point, doesn't work
  }
}
```

I'm quite new to d3.js & javascript, so i'm not sure if i'm approaching this back to front anyways or perhaps i may have missed an inbuilt solution?

Comment: have you tried d.cx? If you called .data on d3.selectAll(".mynode"), and the argument to data contained objects with a cx field, that should work.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Your code is trying to get an svg attribute from an item of data, when what you really want is to get that attribute from the svg DOM element, as in:

```
console.log(d3.selectAll(".mynode").attr("cx"));
```

This will only give you the attribute for the first non-null element of your selection; You can also [filter](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-filter) your selection to get the DOM element you are looking for:

```
console.log(d3.selectAll(".mynode").filter(_conditions_).attr("cx"));
```

Or, if you'd like to access the attributes of all selected elements, use `this` in your each function:

```
d3.selectAll(".mynode").each( function(d, i){
  if(d.someId == targetId){
    console.log( d3.select(this).attr("cx") );
  }
}
```

Comment: i was using `d3.select(this).attr("cx")` before but it was returning `null` , i realised eventually i was requesting the `cx` attribute of an svg group element (doh!) and i had to modify it to `d3.select(this.firstChild).attr("cx")` to get access to my circle element within the group element, i don't like using firstChild/lastChild etc, but it works for now. Also i wouldn't have thought about the filter method if you hadn't suggested it, i'm still not entirely sure how to go about implementing it while searching for specific datum values, but thank you!

Comment: Ill also add that it can return null if you try to access it early in a chain of commands and the particular value has not been set yet.

Answer (score 12):

There is even simpler way: (providing index `i` is given)

```
d3.selectAll("circle")[0][i].attributes.cx.value
```

as it can be seen [here](http://tributary.io/inlet/5817382).

Answer (score 10):

The filter method in the accepted answer is correct. The second approach in the accepted answer (using .each) is incorrect, and contains the same error as the questioner was making: if .data() is not called (which is the case here), then first argument d passed to .each will be undefined (and not the "current dom node", as all newbies, including myself, would expect); the current dom node you get via d3.select(this), which is correct within the if statement at the very end - the error is in the if test condition. Correct version follows.

```
d3.selectAll(".mynode").each(function(d,i){
    var elt = d3.select(this);
    if (elt.attr("id") == "yourTargetIdGoesHere"){
        console.log( elt.attr("cx") );
    }
});
```

fiddle: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mathheadinclouds/RhmLA/) (containing code for both versions, i.e. filter and each)

UPDATE: my answer was assuming that you didn't use .data(), since you did not give the code for that; later I saw that you wrote that you did use .data()

in that case, depending on your data structure, replacing d.attr("cx") by plain d.cx might work.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest here is to give each node a unique id and then select the node with the target id to run your transformation.