# Set attribute of circle from another circle's attribute using d3.select?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I want to place an SVG circles around some SVG circles.  I find the desired circles using `d3.selectAll().filter()`.  This almost works--a circle gets created.  But I can't figure out how to set the center of the new circle from the center of the old circle, so the new circle is created at 0,0.  Nothing I've tried has worked.

```
// first I find the circles I want
foundNodeCircles = d3.selectAll(".node").filter(function(d,i){return d.label == nodeRE;});

// Then I create a new, larger circle for each circle that I found:
svg.selectAll(".nodeHighlightRing")
.data(foundNodeCircles)  // make one ring per node circle
.enter().append("circle") // make the ring
.attr("class", "nodeHighlightRing") // specify its qualities
.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.cx;}) // BROKEN: set center to center of old circle
.attr("cy", function(d) { return d.cy;}) // BROKEN: set center to center of old circle
.attr("r", 10)
.style("opacity", 0)
.style("stroke", "green")
.style("stroke-width", "1.5")
.style("stroke-opacity", "1");
```

In in addition to `d.cx`, I've tried `this.cx`, `d.attr["cx"]`, `this.attr["cx"]`, `d3.select(this).attr("cx")`, `d3.select(d).attr("cx")`, and a few other things that seemed less likely to work.  None were successful.

I thought that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11336251/accessing-d3-js-element-attributes-from-the-datum) question or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17577275/d3-js-transferring-the-value-of-one-attribute-to-another-attribute-for-a-speci) would help, but I am apparently doing something different.

Comment: Can we see what you are getting in foundNodeCircles, or make a fiddle we could do something on it.

Comment: Thanks @saikiran.vsk.  jshanley guessed correctly.  I'll have to learn more about the fiddle world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your variable `foundNodeCircles` is holding a d3 selection, and the data-joining method `.data()` expects an array representing your data.

If you instead use `foundNodeCircles[0]` for your data join you will be referring to the array of elements that were contained in the selection, rather than the selection itself. Then, when you are setting your attributes, `d` will refer to the DOM element itself, so you can either use a d3 selection to select `d` and call `.attr` to retrieve the attribute, or simply use the DOM method `.getAttribute`.

```
svg.selectAll(".nodeHighlightRing")
  // BIND TO THE ELEMENTS RATHER THAN THE SELECTION
  .data(foundNodeCircles[0])
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("class", "nodeHighlightRing")
  // EITHER OF THESE METHODS SHOULD WORK
  .attr("cx", function(d) { return d3.select(d).attr("cx"); })
  .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.getAttribute("cy"); })
  // ... etc. ...
```

Comment: Very illuminating.  I *was* confused about selections vs. arrays and data vs. DOM elements.  It's still odd to me that I can't use `d.cx` here, but I will consider that a lesson to be learned another day.

Comment: Ah, because DOM elements aren't simple Javascript objects (arrays, hashes, whatever they are).  Or rather, attributes aren't regular Javascript fields.  And `d3.select(d).attr()` works because it makes a D3 selection object from the DOM object, and it's only selection objects that have the `.attr()` function?  Not sure if my terminology is completely correct.

Comment: Yep, you're spot on. JavaScript has built-in methods for manipulating DOM elements, and d3 uses them under the hood. When you call `.attr` on a selection, d3 calls the native methods `Element.getAttribute` or `Element.setAttribute` (depending on whether you pass in 1 or 2 arguments, respectively) on the element contained in the selection. That's why the two methods I posted are equivalent.

Comment: Just to avoid confusion, DOM elements (when used this way) *are* plain old JavaScript objects. You can test this out. Go to d3js.org and open up the JavaScript console. Type in `typeof d3.select('div').node()` and you should get back `"object"`.

Comment: Got it.  That additional context is helpful.